# RequireJS sporadic failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, magento2, owl-carousel

I'm working on a Magento2 site. Magento2 uses requirejs and the theme I'm using makes use of it as well. Part of the theme uses [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/). The code used to load the carousel was originally

```
require(['jquery', 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'], function($) {
    $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({
        // carousel settings
    });
});
```

However I noticed sometimes when I load the homepage (where the carousel is used) the carousel doesn't display, and there are errors in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Thinking jQuery might not be loaded, I changed the require code to serialize the requirements

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    require(['owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'], function () {
        $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({
            // ...
```

but this had no effect... Sometimes the carousel loads and there are no errors, other times there are errors and it doesn't load.

Even when there is an error the carousel file has been fetched by the browser. It also seems require has loaded the carousel script per developer tools

[image: Developer Tools]

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that you are loading jQuery through a `script` element *and* through RequireJS. You have to use one method, not both.

If I run this in the console:

```
console.log("owlCarousel", typeof jQuery.fn.owlCarousel)
```

I get:

```
owlCarousel function
```

But with this:

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) { 
  console.log("owlCarousel", typeof $.fn.owlCarousel); 
})
```

I get:

```
owlCarousel undefined
```

And if you try `require(["jquery"], function ($) { console.log("equal", $ === window.jQuery); })` you'll get `equal false`. So you have two instances of jQuery loaded. The code that uses RequireJS to access jQuery gets a version without `.owlCarousel`. That's because Owl Carousel installed itself on `window.jQuery`.

If you must load jQuery through `script` for some reason, you should move the `script` element that loads it *before* you load RequireJS. (You should do this for *all* scripts you load that you want to load with `script` *and* that are AMD-aware.) Then for RequireJS, you should just define this fake module:

```
define("jquery", function () {
    return jQuery;
});
```

This makes it so that when RequireJS loads jQuery it just uses the `jQuery` already defined in the global space. The ideal place for this fake module would be just before you configure RequireJS.

While you're at it you should define a shim for `owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min`:

```
`owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min`: ['jquery']
```

This way there's no need to nest the call to load `owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min` inside a call to load `jquery`. You can just do what you were trying initially:

```
require(['jquery', 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'], function($) {
  $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({
    // carousel settings
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this cogent answer Louis. I'm working with your answer and [the appropriate Magento2 dev docs regarding requirejs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html) to get everything square now.